# How to speed up pulling image speed for k8s cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have one application will start one pod in any node of cluster, but if that node doesn't have this image, it will downloading it the first time and it takes a lot of time (it is around 1gb, and takes more than 3 minutes to download the image), what is the best practice to solve this kind of issue ? Pre pull image or share docker image via nfs ?

Comment: How long is “a lot of time”?  How big are your images?

Comment: Updated the post to include the image size and download time

Answer (score 1):

Deploy a personal docker repository.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the size of the image.
This can be done a few ways depending on your project. For example, if you are using Node you could use `FROM node:11-alpine` instead of `FROM node:11` for a significantly smaller image. Also, make sure you are not putting build files inside the image. Languages like C# and Java have separate build and runtime images. For example, use `java-8-jdk` to build your project but use `java-8-jre` your final image as you only need the runtime.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Continuation to @anskurtis-streutker answer, this page explains in detail how to create smaller images.

[Build smaller images - Kubernetes best practises](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-how-and-why-to-build-small-container-images)

Answer (score -1):

You can give a try to [pod disruption budget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/). With it you can achieve high availability in your app and the download time shouldn't be a problem.

Regards

Comment: The question is about reducing the time taken to pull container images. I am not sure how the pod distruption budget will help. Can you please explain?

Comment: You're talking about the time to download a image, this only affects when you deploy a new version or in a first time deployment. If  you''re providing a service to your cliente you need a guarantee of service for him.  If you can guarantee  that the service is up, the size or time to download doesn't matter.